# presentViewController with custom transition

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, transition

I would like to present a modal UIViewController with a different transitions to the ones available by the toolkit. Precisely I'd like an inverted animation compared to the slide from the bottom (UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical), present = slide in from the top, dismiss = slide out from the top.

I don't think there is a simply option for UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical to be inverted, so I guess I need to make one on my own.

I am also not using segue/storyboard either, not sure if this makes a difference.

I found some solutions which suggest to simply animate the new viewcontroller view and use presentViewController with the animated option as NO. Unfortunately the problem I have is that the background turns black straight away, even If I define the new viewcontroller view with clear background and not opaque.

Any idea how I could sort this out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you show how you are trying to animate your controller right now? otherwise it will be pretty difficult to say why the background turns black...

Comment: you could try custom animation like this...                 `CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;`

Comment: Looks like the solution is using a screenshot, the problem I got is that it's taking too long 700ms, looking into it...

Comment: I would actually prefer not to use the screenshot workaround. Will try the custom animation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the not transparent background issue taking a screenshot and using it as background for the modal view controller.

Comment: Haha, just found this question when looking for a solution for the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply your custom animation with CATransition.
2. Set `modalPresentationStyle` property for the presented view controller to UIModalPresentationCustom (available for iOS 7 or later). See also UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext iOS8, or UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.

For my case I wanted to the same animation style, but I only needed to use UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext for iOS 8.